# I-V characteristic of Diodes

Tags: diodes

I need to develop mathematical equations (models) to represent the I-V characteristics of a Zener Diode, Signal Diode and Rectifier Diode. I have done research and I've only been able to come up with Shockley's diode equation which gives the I–V characteristic of an ideal diode.

[image: Shockley's diode equation]

What would the mathematical models for these three diodes be?

After additional research, it seems as though what I've been looking for are piecewise equations to model the diodes behaviours.

For example:
[image: Piecewise Equation]
http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/diode.html

Any suggestions on what the equations would be?
Thanks!

Comment: If you are developing (deriving?) a model, this question would belong to physics (of semiconductor devices). See ch 4 here http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/contents.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I can totally answer this, but I'll write down what I know.

The equation that you've given is the voltage of a diode, assuming that the diode is **not in breakdown**. If you apply a high reverse voltage to the diode, all bets are off - it enters breakdown, and your equation doesn't tell us anything about the breakdown region.

So, what's different about these three types of diodes?

- Signal and rectifier diodes have the same voltage-current characteristic. As far as I know, the only difference is that rectifier diodes are made a bit tougher for high voltages and currents (think of a rectifier circuit) while signal diodes are meant for lower operating points. They both follow the Shockley equation.
- Zener diodes act differently in the breakdown region - while 'regular' diodes go into *avalanche breakdown*, Zener diodes go into *Zener breakdown* (go figure), which happens at a specific voltage. Take a look at the reverse voltage portion of a typical Zener diode (and note that the forward voltage part still matches the Shockley equation):

[image: Zener diode IV curve]

Comment: Nice (+1), If you look right at the knee of a avalanche "zener" (Vbr > 7 V or so) you'll find that the current is not stationary but highly chaotic.. random breakdowns.  So modelling that region would be harder.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold ...and the mathematical model is....?

Comment: @GRTech,  I've never tried to model it... I guess a capacitor,  in parallel with a resistor and a series switch.  The closing and opening of the switch will depend on the voltage.. but is also  random.

Comment: @Kynit After doing additional research it seems as if piecewise equations to model the diodes behavior is the way to go. Any suggestions?

Comment: Good plan. Depending on your needs, you could do three pieces (forward bias, reverse bias, breakdown) or two (Shockley, breakdown) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for a real diode forward voltage characterisrtic, the shape is like this

[image]

that can modeling using the equation

[image]

The A,B and C are constants sets by the manufacturers.

However, you can simplify the curve like this

[image]

using the equation

[image]

where Vto=Threshold voltage and Rto=slope resistance. This values are giving by the manufacturer for low level and for high level.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It is an accurate answer for the forward bias region of pin diodes (and thyristors), very usefull in case of power dissipation simulation.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP's question was.